# How can I create Scroll at Java?

Tags: java, user-interface

Now I study about GUI (awt&swing) in java. But I don't know how can I make scroll bar. I try to find about that matter but still i don't get it. Could you give me simple explanation and example to create it.

Thank you . I am sorry for my bad English.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html - The best explanation you can get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java offers the `JScrollPane` object for this sort of thing. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) is the documentation.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) is a tutorial provided by Oracle on how to use them.

**Example**

```
JTextArea t = new JTextArea("This is some text");
JScrollPane s = new JScrollPane(t);
this.add(s); // Adds the scollpane to the parent container.
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a example for [swing scroll bar](http://examples.oreilly.com/jswing2/code/ch06/ScrollBarExample.java)

and here is an example for [awt scroll bar](http://java.comsci.us/examples/awt/Scrollbar.html)